# Voice UI or Speech recognition using C# speech recognition libraries

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cortana-skills-kit

Being that Im a C++ Developer, Curious to know if its possible to develop Voice UI and Speech recoginition Software like Amazon alexa but using c# speech libraries to open a specific Software through voice commands?

Can someone give some insight or einlighten me ? I used Speech.Recognition from C# and wrote a sample Code, where in it Can take my Input, but the Problem is it coudnt understand my Input that perfectly.

Is it a good idea to continue to work on this ? I feel like totally lost. Any Inputs will be apprerciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible - but depends on if you want to go through the trouble of recreating all the Voice based assistants & technology already available for you to leverage.

For example, you could easily create a Skill using the Cortana Skills Kit, and enable Cortana to be the digital assistant that does the speech to text, provide context, enable deep-linking to your software etc. while you focus on the business logic/functionality. Does that help?

Comment: I created test Version of speech recognition using c# Libraries, it seems to work as of now, but not sure how powerful is it when compared to ALexa Sdk